nested flexbox with text truncation
I have a set of nested flexboxes, each with a flex-1 div on the left and a fixed width div on the right. I want the inner-most left div to take up available space and truncate its text if necessary.
Here is an example I prepared: Tailwind Play
Resize the window to see what happens with the text in each case.
Example A shows the problem I am seeing where the text does not truncate.
Example B shows a single flexbox where the text does truncate.
What changes are needed on Example A so that the text does truncate?
Thanks!

It's a very classic CSS gotcha. By default, flex-box respect the min-width despite having flex-shrink, while most elements having min-width: min-content. Giving the outmost flex-1 a min-w-0 class solves this problem.
<div class="m-3 flex border">
  <div class="flex-1 min-w-0"> <!-- added -->
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="flex-1 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="truncate">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-none w-14 bg-red-500 py-4 text-center">2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-none w-14 bg-blue-500 p-4 text-center">1</div>
</div>


wow, ok. I don't understand why min-w-0 is not required in Example B, but thanks for the answer!

Because Example B only has one flexbox layer and it already got handled by overflow-hidden. If you are not sure which container needs to have it, assigning a global * { min-width: 0; } style like most reset CSS does is also a viable option. Which solves these kind of traps once and for all and has very minimal impact on your code.

oh, i see now. As you said in your answer, min-width: min-content is the default for most elements.
